# How can I migrate an application from GitHub to Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I am working on a new [Ubuntu application](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor).

I would like to migrate it from GitHub to Launchpad.

The reason why I added it to GitHub and not to Launchpad is that I had some issues saving it with `quickly` (some `bzr`-related problem probably). So I deleted my `.bzr` folder.

What is the easiest way to add it to Launchpad and `bzr` now?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is probably to do so using `bzr-git`.

Clone the repository that is currently on GitHub:

```
$ bzr branch git://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor
```

After that you can push it to Launchpad, assuming you've created a project on Launchpad named 'revision-monitor':

```
$ cd revision-monitor
$ bzr push lp:revision-monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this probably duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/a/854862/349837):

> Launchpad [supports importing git code
>   directly](http://blog.launchpad.net/code/git-to-git-imports) since
>   2016-10-16, see [the
>   doc](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes) for
>   setup instructions.
>
> **A note:** if [1084403](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bzr-git/+bug/1084403)
>   bug still open when you're reading this, don't forget to clean your
>   bzr import settings from old setup or you couldn't set a recipe for
>   git code even if it's there.