# How to set up Launchpad to import from GitHub?

Tags: application-development, launchpad, github

I'm setting up my first Launchpad project.

In this case I would like to import from the Master branch from my [GitHub project](https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser) - the default branch is not Master - it is a release branch currently called "Release-0.6"

On Launchpad I have set up to automatically import:

[image]

As you can see, the import failed - the error log states:

```
2013-01-07 14:45:11 INFO    Starting job.
2013-01-07 14:45:11 INFO    Getting exising bzr branch from central store.
2013-01-07 14:45:14 INFO    [chan bzr SocketAsChannelAdapter] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2013-01-07 14:45:17 INFO    [chan bzr SocketAsChannelAdapter] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2013-01-07 14:45:17 INFO    291 bytes transferred
2013-01-07 14:45:18 INFO    No branch found at remote location.
```

This is strange since my GitHub project is obviously at the correct web-location.

Thus - what have I done wrong in my configuration?

i.e. how should I have set up my Launchpad project to import from Github?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the "read-only git location" as shown on github. It is the same as the web URL (which you have used), but with `.git` appended to the end. You need to add this to the end of your URL.

To import a non-master branch, you must also append `,branch=branchname` to the end of the URL.

Also, I think you may be confusing the term "master branch" with "branch named master" in this case. For your project, pulling https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser.git will give the contents of what you are calling release-0.6. I think omitting the `,branch=name` piece will give what you want. However, when trying to branch your repository in bzr, I get the following error:

```
bzr: ERROR: Unknown extra fields in <Commit 3f47f3ed4e9e6f15a6c5229bf36d061ae4d86605>: ['gpgsig', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''].
```

This may cause importing to fail on Launchpad as well.

Comment: My default branch is not "Master" - so this will not work?

Comment: I'll test - but according to this bug report may not be possible - https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1000852

Comment: There are two bugs, the UI issue described in that bug, and the other issue which another user describes in his comments. He really should file a separate bug.

Answer (score 3):

Launchpad [supports importing git code directly](http://blog.launchpad.net/code/git-to-git-imports) since 16-10-2016, see [the doc](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes) for setup instructions.

A note: if [1084403](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bzr-git/+bug/1084403) bug still open when you're reading this, don't forget to clean your bzr import settings from old setup or you couldn't set a recipe for git code even if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the unsupported ,branch=branchname is to create a fork on github first with with the default branch set to the branch you want to import.